# How to check program start parameters from Windows Console?

Tags: c++, parameters, argv, argc

At the start of my program, it should get path to the input file and path to the output file from the console.
But if user give not required number of parameters or wrong parameters (with spaces for example, or without ".txt") it should give the user second chance to enter those parameters without exiting the program. Is it possible?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ //and here should be something to check if the user entered parameters correctly 
//(number and if they look like a path) and give a user another try if this is wrong 
//(so that user enter them from console again)

string path_open(argv[1]);
  strin path_out(argv[2]);
```

Comment: ***Is it possible?*** Yes this is certainly possible. Also in your example code you should check argc before using argv[1] ...

Comment: Yes, it's possible to ask the user again. But why would you consider this? If the user enters garbage, write an error message and exit. There is no compelling reason to write code, that gives the user a second chance. If they need a second chance, have them invoke your program again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but... weird. If you are going to have your program ask for input, why not just put **that** in a loop until you get proper input? Ultimately, I'd do one or the other:

1. Get command line input (and, as @IInspectable suggests in the comments, if it's not valid, exit the program); OR
2. Have program ask for input recursively until the user gives valid input.

**Input from command line**:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // sanity check to see if the right amount of arguments were provided:
    if (argc < 3)
        return 1;
    // process arguments:
    if (!path_open(argv[1]))
        return 1;
    if (!path_out(argv[2]))
        return 1;
}

bool path_open(const std::string& path)
{
    // verify path is correct...
}
```

**Program asks for input:**

```
int main()
{
    std::string inputPath, outputPath;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Insert input path: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, inputPath);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Insert output path ";
        std::getline(std::cin, outputPath);
    } while (!(path_open(inputPath) && path_out(outputPath)));
}
```

Of course you'd validate input separately in case they were entering a valid input path but invalid output path, but you get the gist.